# PostgreSQL Need rows to return even if the result is 0

Tags: postgresql, join

I know this has been asked a bit on here and I have tried several of the answers with no progress. My goal is to be able to also see which Tracking Numbers had 0 calls during the date range.

I have tried several joins, sub-queries, and way to much time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT org_unit_name "Group Name", 
       call_detail.ring_to_name "Ad Source(s)", 
       tracking "Tracking Number", 
       COUNT(call.call_id)"Calls", 
       SUM(bill_second)/60 "Total Duration (Sec)" 
FROM CALL
  JOIN call_detail ON call.call_id = call_detail.call_id
  JOIN org_unit o ON call.org_unit_id = o.org_unit_id
WHERE billing_id = 3104 
  AND call_started BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
GROUP BY 1,2,3


Here is a sample of how the data is coming back:
| Group Name               | Ad Source(s)                 | Tracking Number | Calls | Total Duration (Sec) |
|--------------------------|------------------------------|-----------------|-------|----------------------|
| Westin Riverfront Villas | Desert Willow Explorer       | 8883926768      | 2     | 9                    |
| Sheraton Maui            | Postcard-Owner               | 8885322865      | 36    | 82                   |
| Westin Maui              | CS On-Site Pre Arrival calls | 8885939052      | 35    | 128                  |
| Sheraton Kauai           | Email Renter                 | 8887248492      | 24    | 91                   |

But I need 6th and 8th line to show up as well even/especially since they have had no calls. 
Westin Princeville and Westin Nanea Resort had no calls but should be on the report

| Group Name               | Ad Source(s)                    | Tracking Number | Calls | Total Duration (Sec) |
|--------------------------|---------------------------------|-----------------|-------|----------------------|
| Westin Maui              | CS On-Site Pre Arrival calls    | 8885939052      | 35    | 128                  |
| Westin Riverfront Villas | Desert Willow Explorer          | 8883926768      | 2     | 9                    |
| Sheraton Kauai           | Email Renter                    | 8887248492      | 24    | 91                   |
| Westin Princeville       | In-House pre-arrival phone call | 8776921840      | 0     | 0                    |
| Sheraton Maui            | Postcard-Owner                  | 8885322865      | 36    | 82                   |
| Westin Nanea Resort      | Pre-Arrival E-Mail Nanea WVP    | 8887218839      | 0     | 0                    |
```

Comment: You want a `left join`

Comment: That what I thought and it did not work, I then went through and tried all joins (mostly becouse they are still mysteries to me) I don't think to throw a "left" in this would work, would you suggest rewriting the "from"?

Comment: @user3708763 can you provide a few data samples and the exact expected result? I still believe that a `left join` is what you're looking for, but I cannot be sure without the data.

Comment: This query is basically counting how many calls each tracking number received during the date period. Some of the tracking numbers did not get any calls during this period but we still need them on this report. 

call and call_detail are basically the same just call_detail allows me to join the org_unit. 

If this was working as desired I would get 76 rows of data but I am only getting 51 rows. I am getting less becouse 25 of the tracking numbers did not get calls on them.

I have rewritten with every join combination I can think of an I am still getting only 51 rows of data.

Comment: @user3708763 can you show your existing data and expected data?